# How to sort services based on their Startup type

Tags: powershell-3.0

The following command works as I expect it:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.status -eq 'running'}
```

However this one does not:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.startmode -eq 'manual'}
```

Could anyone explain why that is? **How do I sort services based on their start up type?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's as simple as accessing the correct property. Get-Service returns an array of `ServiceController` objects. The property you're looking for is called `StartType`. So
`Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Starttype -eq 'Manual'}`
should get you what you're looking for.

If you ever need to look at all the properties and methods of a given object you can always pipe it to `Get-Member`.

So in this instance you could so something like
`Get-Service | select -First 1 | Get-Member`

This is getting the first instance of the ServiceController from the list and showing you all the member properties and methods.

Also, if you're just getting started I would recommend jumping on a book or blog series that will give you a good foundation so you don't spend too much time banging your head. [Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month Lunches](http://a.co/itfsNIn)  is great for a sysadmin learning powershell.

Comment: Thank you so much. You made it so crystal clear with additional information. Much appreciated. :)